# Google-gax issue when instanciating dialogflow.IntentsClient()

Tags: typescript, dialogflow-es

I'm setting up a backend in Typescript for my google dialogflow vocal assistant. 
I'm trying to use the google client ClientIntents from dialogflow dependency but I'm not able to instanciate this one.

```js
class DialogFlowService {

  constructor() {
  }

  public createNewQuestion() {
    const config = {
      credentials: {
        private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n*******************==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        client_email: "****-****@****-****.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      }
    }

    const client = new dialogflow.v2.IntentsClient(config)
```

Already tryed to instanciate the client without any config, like in this samples (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/resource.js). 
But this will give the same result.

It should be as simple as this...

The error occurs in the root.js file.

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Root.load (/home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:192:44)
    at Root.loadSync (/home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:235:17)
    at Object.loadSync (/home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:230:27)
    at GrpcClient.loadFromProto (/home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/node_modules/dialogflow/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:118:44)
    at GrpcClient.loadProto (/home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/node_modules/dialogflow/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:145:21)
    at new IntentsClient (/home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/node_modules/dialogflow/src/v2/intents_client.js:151:28)
    at DialogFlowService.createNewQuestion (/home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/src/services/DialogFlowService.ts:31:20)
    at UploadFileController.<anonymous> (/home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/src/controllers/UploadFileController.ts:132:22)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/****/Bureau/Voice/Projets/voice-****-backend/dist/controllers/UploadFileController.js:8:71
```

In intents_client.js (Module google)

```
const protos = gaxGrpc.loadProto(
      opts.fallback ? require('../../protos/protos.json') : nodejsProtoPath
    );
```

loadProto method takes two arguments : protoPath, and filename. Filename is undefined, that's what's causing the previous exception.

Thanks you for help, i'm getting mad...

Comment: Node version : v12.11.1

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?